# Android MaterialSearchView overlap

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-xml, android-appbarlayout

I'm using MaterialSearchView in my project.

https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView.

I'm creating the the **Navigation Drawer Activiti** that Android Studio provides, the default xml is using **CoordinatorLayout** to contain **AppBarLayout**. However, when integrate with the MaterialSearchView library, **only one suggestion** is given. I found in their sample xml, they are using RelativeLayout. After I change to **RelativeLayout**, the suggestions display fine. However, the FrameLayout and AppLayout seems **overlap** each other. After I click the search menu item, and close it, then it look fine. (Check the below pictures)

[image] [image] [image]

Current code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.toe.shareyourcuisine.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

            <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I also post my issue in this link:

https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView/issues/141

Can anyone help me figure it out?

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem and the solution is little tricky. To make all the suggestion displayed just place the FrameLayout containing the Toolbar and MaterialSearch view tag as its child tags at the end of the layout file.
i.e. change you layout file to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.toe.shareyourcuisine.activity.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```